# How to make a transparent form to be painted

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Before asking a question, I'm sorry that I'm not a native speaker on English so my sentence can be awkward. My question is below.

I'm making a project to draw on transparent windows form.
I uses c# to make this project. The code I made is below.

```
    public NoteForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    public void PaintOnForm()
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5);

        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 50, 50);

        Console.WriteLine("write!");
    }
```

and I tried this too.

```
    public NoteForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        TransparencyKey = Color.Blue;
    }

    public void PaintOnForm()
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5);

        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 50, 50);

        Console.WriteLine("write!");
    }
```

When I try to make the background opaque, It draws the line correctly.
However, When I try to make the background transparent, no line is shown.

How to make a transparant windows form to be painted?

If there is solution with other way to be made with C#(ex. WPF), Could you please let me know?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms? The two are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a WPF window transparent, there are a couple of properties you need to set.  Background="Transparent", AllowTransparency="True" and WindowStyle="None":

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Background="Transparent"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None">
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" />
</Border>
```

With regards to drawing on the window, I'd recommend drawing on a canvas.
A canvas will have no background brush defined unless you define one, so you don't have to do anything special there.

To draw your line, assuming you want to do it in code (you could do it in XAML, depends on your use case):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var line = new Line { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), StrokeThickness = 5, X1 = 0, Y1 = 0, X2 = 50, Y2 = 50 };
        this.Canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
```